# Move text box control at place of selected item inside a list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to move a textbox1 control inside listbox1 control at selected listbox's item's place at runtime. Lets say the selected place inside a list is 1. I am working in c# wpf application inside a grid. 
Anybody knows ?

Comment: You question is quite a mess, it's hardly intelligible and the title says *"move"* while in the first sentence you say *"copy"* which isn't quite the same, further you do not need to mention C# and WPF in your question since that information is in the tags already.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you *really* want to do is have the `TextBox.Text` bound to the currently selected list item. Here is an example:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextbox" Width="100" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"                 
                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=MyListBox}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This just copies the strings item1, item2, item3 to textbox1. I can do this in cs so that i can copy, modify it, delete it, add it...but i want my textbox1 control to be moved where the selected item of listbox1 is, not copy the string of listbox to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
Private Sub MoveTextBox(TxtBox as TextBox, LBox as listbox, index as integer)
            lBox.items.remove(lbox.indexof(TxtBox));
        Dim l as ListBoxItem = lBox.items(index);
        l.content = TxtBox;
End Sub
```

Just write MoveTextBox(Which TextBox you want to move,listbox to which the txtbox belongs and to which you want to move, the index where you want the textbox to be moved(Remember index starts from 0)
Sorry, I don't know how to get this to run with C#.